# R code to iterate through dataframe rows for google maps distance queries

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, google-distancematrix-api

I'm looking for some assistance in writing some R code to iterate through rows in a dataframe and pass the values in each row to a function and print the output either to an excel file, txt file or just in the console.

The purpose of this is to automate a bunch of distance/time queries (several hundred) to google maps using the function found at this website: http://www.nfactorialanalytics.com/r-vignette-for-the-week-finding-time-distance-between-two-places/

The function on that website is as follows:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
distance2Points <- function(origin,destination){
 results <- list();
 xml.url <- paste0('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=',origin,'&destinations=',destination,'&mode=driving&sensor=false')
 xmlfile <- xmlParse(getURL(xml.url))
 dist <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xpathApply(xmlfile,"//distance")[[1]])$value)
 time <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xpathApply(xmlfile,"//duration")[[1]])$value)
 distance <- as.numeric(sub(" km","",dist))
 time <- as.numeric(time)/60
 distance <- distance/1000
 results[['time']] <- time
 results[['dist']] <- distance
 return(results)
}
```

The dataframe will contain two columns: origin postal code and destination postal code (Canada, eh?). I'm a beginner R programmer, so I know how to use read.table to load a txt file into a dataframe. I'm just not sure how iterate through the dataframe, each time passing values to the distance2Points function and executing. I think this can be done using either a for loop or one of the apply calls?

Thanks for the help!

edit:

To keep it simple lets assume I want to transform these two vectors into a dataframe

```
> a <- c("L5B4P2","L5B4P2")
> b <- c("M5E1E5", "A2N1T3")
> postcodetest <- data.frame(a,b)
> postcodetest
       a      b
1 L5B4P2 M5E1E5
2 L5B4P2 A2N1T3
```

How should I go about iterating over these two rows to return both distances and times from the distance2Points function?

Comment: I think `sapply` will do what you want, with the function you've shown here as the function you use in the call to `sapply`. It's hard to be more specific, though, when you haven't provided a reproducible example. If you could use `dput` to include a snippet of your data in the question, that would do it.

Comment: @ulfelder not sure if this helps but I've created a sample dataframe as something to work with. I can't add much more than that since I'm not sure how to use sapply to solve my problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using `lapply` to produce a list with the results for each row in your data and using `Reduce(rbind, [yourlist])` to concatenate that list into a data frame whose rows correspond to the ones in your original. To make this work, we also have to tweak the code in the original function to return a one-row data frame, so I've done that here.

```
distance2Points <- function(origin,destination){

  require(XML)
  require(RCurl)

  xml.url <- paste0('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=',origin,'&destinations=',destination,'&mode=driving&sensor=false')
  xmlfile <- xmlParse(getURL(xml.url))
  dist <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xpathApply(xmlfile,"//distance")[[1]])$value)
  time <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xpathApply(xmlfile,"//duration")[[1]])$value)
  distance <- as.numeric(sub(" km","",dist))
  time <- as.numeric(time)/60
  distance <- distance/1000
  # this gives you a one-row data frame instead of a list, b/c it's easy to rbind
  results <- data.frame(time = time, distance = distance)
  return(results)
}

# now apply that function rowwise to your data, using lapply, and roll the results
# into a single data frame using Reduce(rbind)
results <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(postcodetest)), function(i)
  distance2Points(postcodetest$a[i], postcodetest$b[i])))
```

Result when applied to your sample data:

```
> results
        time distance
1   27.06667   27.062
2 1797.80000 2369.311
```

If you would prefer to do this without creating a new object, you could also write separate functions for computing time and distance -- or a single function with those outputs as options -- and then use `sapply` or just `mutate` to create new columns in your original data frame. Here's how that might look using `sapply`:

```
distance2Points <- function(origin, destination, output){

  require(XML)
  require(RCurl)

  xml.url <- paste0('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=',
                    origin, '&destinations=', destination, '&mode=driving&sensor=false')

  xmlfile <- xmlParse(getURL(xml.url))

  if(output == "distance") {

    y <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xpathApply(xmlfile,"//distance")[[1]])$value)
    y <- as.numeric(sub(" km", "", y))/1000

  } else if(output == "time") {

    y <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xpathApply(xmlfile,"//duration")[[1]])$value)
    y <- as.numeric(y)/60

  } else {

    y <- NA    

  }

  return(y)

}

postcodetest$distance <- sapply(seq(nrow(postcodetest)), function(i)
  distance2Points(postcodetest$a[i], postcodetest$b[i], "distance"))

postcodetest$time <- sapply(seq(nrow(postcodetest)), function(i)
  distance2Points(postcodetest$a[i], postcodetest$b[i], "time"))
```

And here's how you could do it in a `dplyr` pipe with `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

postcodetest <- postcodetest %>%
  mutate(distance = sapply(seq(nrow(postcodetest)), function(i)
           distance2Points(a[i], b[i], "distance")),
         time = sapply(seq(nrow(postcodetest)), function(i)
           distance2Points(a[i], b[i], "time")))
```

Comment: Thanks @ulfelder! Great solution! I liked the simplicity and how it returned the results to a dataframe which I could easily work with. I feel like I now have a tool which can be used again in the future for any similar projects.